# How to initialize objects inside two dimensional array?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I got a two dimensional Array

```
BoardTile tiles[,];
```

and then in `Init(Point size)` I set its size:

```
tiles = new BoardTile[size.X, size.Y];
```

And how do I *initialize* all those elements because it does not use default `BoardTile()` constructor. It just assigns `null`.

`foreach(BoardTile t in tiles) t = new BoardTile()`

*Does not work*. And when I try to call

```
foreach(BoardTile t in tiles) t.anything()
```

I get `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Use a for loop for each dimension. That's shown in all array tutorials. `foreach` is introduced for enumerating collections

Comment: Also that's not a dynamically sized array, the array size will not change after initialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try *nested loops*:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < titles.GetLength(0); ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < titles.GetLength(1); ++j)
      titles[i, j] = new BoardTile();
```

**Edit:** if *nested loops* are too complex and unreadable, try switching to *jagged arrays* i.e. array of array - `BoardTile tiles[][];` - from *2D* one `BoardTile tiles[,]`, e.g.

```
   // created and initialized jagged array
   BoardTile tiles[][] = Enumerable
     .Range(size.Y)                      // size.Y lines
     .Select(y => Enumerable             // each line is
        .Range(size.X)                   //   size.X items
        .Select(x => new BoardTile())    //   each of them is BoardTile()
        .ToArray())                      //   materialized as array
     .ToArray();                         // all arrays are array of array
```

Comment: Is it the only way? I thought about this solution, but this looks for me like it could be done easier.

Comment: @SkillGG: unlike *jagged* arrays (array of array `BoardTile[][]`) *multidimensional* ones (`BoardTile[,]`) are not very handy.

Comment: Okay. Thank for your help. I guess I'm stuck with this ugly double-loop init.